# Getting user input in ArcPy using GetParameterAsText()

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-script-tool

[image]

I am writing a script to be included in a toolbox but every time I am getting an error when I try to include the parameter using `GetParameterAsText()`.

```
import numpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *


input_raster= arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
inputFeature= arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
clipRaster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
floodedArea = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
output_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
```

and the error I get is...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\dealingwithraster.py", line 16, in <module>
    output_folder =arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 655, in GetParameterAsText
    return gp.getParameterAsText(index)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 226, in getParameterAsText
    self._gp.GetParameterAsText(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
RuntimeError: Object: Error in getting parameter as text

Failed to execute (dealingWithRaster).
```

Help needed because I can't seem to figure out the problem.

Comment: You have 5 input parameters in the code but only 4 in the script parameters. They must match in number and order/index.

Answer (score 2):

You have 5 input parameters in the code but only 4 in the script parameters. They must match in number and order/index.

You are missing `floodedArea` in the script parameters.